# Asking compiler to inline my class and apply usual optimizations

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, inline

Let's say I have a few variants of the same algorithm that operate on a certain data structure. The algorithm is critical and needs to be as performant as possible.

I can:

1. Copy paste the data structure manipulators in every variant of the algorithm with manual optimizations. The algorithms are small enough and won't change in the future, so actually it's somewhat feasible. Example:

   ```
   int buf[0x100]; // I know it's going to be 0x100, so...
   for (...) {
       buf[i & 0xFF] // I can use something like this
     //buf[i % 0x100] // rather than this.
   }
   ```

   Heck, I don't even need to do that `& 0xFF` thing, cause every compiler figures it out for me and evaluates it to `and eax, 0xFF`.
2. Implement the data structure with all of the possible operations as a separate class. Now it looks like this:

   ```
   class Buffer {
   public:
       void operation1(int i) { return buf[i % buf.size()]; }
       void operation2() { ... }
   private:
       std::vector<int> buf;
   };
   ```

   and later:

   ```
   Buffer b(0x100);
   for (...)
       b.operation1(i);
   ```

   now that's what I call readable, and more importantly, reusable code! Needless to say, I want to use it.

   But now I can't do the earlier optimizations because I don't know the size of the buf, and neither does the compiler. **Furthermore** with this variant I'm facing a penalty in form of function calls, which includes resolving the class member/methods, manipulating the stack, yada yada...

When I benchmark the second solution, it's 20% slower, so my program takes 10 minutes to run rather than 8. The 2 minute penalty could be avoided if I **could tell C++ compiler to completely inline `Buffer` and apply usual optimizations**.

Is there any technique that allows me to do just that (templates, `constexpr`s, anything really), or am I forced to "unroll" the code manually?

(Compiler-specific solutions would be last resort.)

Comment: You don't need the `std::vector` if its size is known at compile time, you can just have an array or `std::array` member. You can also template the class wrt the size to increase reusability if that is desired.

Comment: Yep, just make your `Buffer` templated on the size and use `array` instead of a `vector` and you should be fine.

Comment: I haven't thought of this. That's a very good idea, I'll benchmark it right away.

Comment: Well, it improved things a little, here are actual times for the current variant I work with: direct arrays - 5.6m, naive class - 10.3m, class with templated size - 7.6m. But there's still plenty of room for improvements.

Comment: if you post a (minimal) example of your test we could look at suggesting optimisations. It's likely that you'll see a bigger improvement from changes in algorithm structure rather than seeking to do the compiler's job for it.

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't think the algorithm is relevant here - my question was how can I avoid penalties coming from introduction of high level classes, so that I stay on the same performance level as if I didn't use them. Whether the specific algorithm's performance could be improved by choosing a different design would be a different question, possibly less useful for broad audience.

Comment: That being said I made an error in my last benchmark - turns out class with templated size actually uses 5.7m, which is practically **as good as the manual unroll approach**. @BaummitAugen could you convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily hiding the size information from the compiler by using the runtime sized `std::vector`. Something like

```
template <std::size_t len>
class Buffer {
public:
    void operation1(int i) { return buf[i % buf.size()]; }
    void operation2() { ... }
private:
    std::array<int, len> buf;
};
```

should give the optimizer the information it needs to optimize just as in the "raw array in function" case.